# DNS Redirecting in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, dns, redirection

The other day we were attempting to redirect traffic in my office. We wanted to redirect YouTube, Facebook, and other similar sites back to our website. Originally the plan was to just use the Hosts file (these are all windows systems), since we don't have any kind of domain controller.

This worked, and redirected command prompt, IE and FireFox. However, Chrome completely ignored the rules. It listens to other rules that allowed us to set up custom domains internally, but it ignores overwrites for sites such as YouTube.

I have tried `ipconfig /flushdns` and I've gone into Chrome settings to turn off DNS prefetching, as well as visiting chrome://net-internals and removing `clear host cache`.

We have even created rules in our firewall to redirect traffic for certain domains, and Chrome somehow manages to ignore those as well, while everything else follows along.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @jiggunjer Unfortunately not.